# Trouble with a menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, menu

I am having some trouble with a menu in Elementor. Please see this page: https://boys-cry.com/ On the first 2 menu items, 'We' and 'Clients' I have set up a popup of text to appear under the menu when each is clicked. However when one is clicked, you can't click on a different one without 'closing the popup' first by click away underneath the text to close that popup and then the menu becomes clickable again.

The desired outcome I am trying to achieve is like the menu on this page: https://www.am-production.co.uk/ where the text appears underneath each menu item that expands when clicked. Any ideas on some help for a method or plugin to achieve this please?
Thank you!

Code of the logo/menu button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  color: #00000000;
  padding: 40px 12px 40px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: #00000000;
  padding: 40px 12px 40px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.dropbtn:focus {
  color: #00000000;
  padding: 40px 12px 40px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00000000;
  min-width: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

hr.solid {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="#we">WE</a>
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="mailto:info@boys-cry.com">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    <hr class="solid">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Margin is comming from top.. so you need to change it]

I have change some CSS .. you may apply it and get your desire result..

```
.elementor-469 .elementor-element.elementor-element-148ab54 {
transition: background 0.3s, border 0.3s, border-radius 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
margin-top: unset !important;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
z-index: 0;
position: absolute  !important;
top: 220px  !important;
width: 100%  !important;
```

}

Thanks & Enjoy

Comment: Yes this worked well thank you!! I dont suppose you know how to put the text from each of those to underneath each menu item making the rest of the menu expandable and collapsible as each on is clicked? like this website menu: https://www.am-production.co.uk/ ? thanks again

Comment: for this easy way to use accordion or collapse .. that's easy to write text underneath